# Why is the Cancel button in UISearchBar stretched out when customizing the appearance?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, uisearchbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have a plain `UISearchBar` in the `titleView` of my `UINavigationBar`:

[image: search bar]

When the user starts searching, the Cancel button is shown:

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
    return YES;
}
```

Which looks like this:

[image: cancel button]

Now I would like to customize the appearance and use a different Cancel button:

```
id appearance = [UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil];
[appearance setTitle:@""];
[appearance setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[appearance setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel_pressed.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

The result looks like this:

[image: customized appearance]

My custom Cancel button is about 60 pixels wide but somehow gets stretched to over 80 pixels.
The documentation for `setBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:` does mention that "for good results, backgroundImage must be a stretchable image", but it feels like a waste to have the Cancel button occupy that much screen estate (especially since I want to add a left bar item as well).

I can work around this by iterating the subviews but I would prefer to use the appearance proxy approach. So the question is why the Cancel button becomes so much wider once you customize its appearance.

Comment: how did you add label on the button

Comment: The second image which has cancel button stretched is after pressing the cancel button, is it?

Comment: There is no label in the customized appearance, only an image with the Cancel text pre-rendered in it. The second image is after pressing the search field, not after pressing the Cancel button.

Comment: you got any solution I am facing same issue!!